# git cannot see external diff tool that is in path

Tags: git, cygwin

In my `.gitconfig`, I have this:

```
[diff]
  external = extDiff
```

`extDiff` is a wrapper script which is in my bash PATH.

I can successfully call it from (cygwin) bash, and it successfully launches.

But when I try `git diff <ref1> <ref2>`, I get this error:

```
error: cannot run extDiff: No such file or directory
fatal: external diff died, stopping at file2.txt
```

This is the same error I get if I put in something bogus for diff.external.

If `extDiff` is in my path, why can't git see it, and what can I do to work around this problem?

Comment: maybe try with a fullpath

Answer (score 0):

If `git` is not reading your `PATH` correctly on `cygwin`, there could be any number of causes including `git` trying to read your Windows `PATH` variable instead.

As Alex Tartan mentioned in his comment, the easiest workaround is to use the full path to the tool.